# Checking Clicked Element in Bubbling

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling, propagation

I was tinkering with event bubbling and I created the typical 3 divs each other exercise for myself and I was able to get the code working and event to stop "bubbling" where I wanted.

My code was clunky so I tried to make it a little more simplified. By having all my `<divs>` point to a single function, that had a statement that said if **this** `<div>` was clicked, run the function and then stop propagation, but I believe the way I am "checking" the click is wrong.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/theodore_steiner/t5r5kov0/3/

```js
var d1 = document.getElementById("d1");
var d2 = document.getElementById("d2");
var d3 = document.getElementById("d3");

function showme(event) {
  if (d3.onclick == true) {
    alert("hello")
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    alert("hello");
  }
};

d1.addEventListener("click", showme);
d2.addEventListener("click", showme);
d3.addEventListener("click", showme);
```

```css
 #d1 {
   height: 300px;
   width: 300px;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
 #d2 {
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
 #d3 {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2">
    <div id="d3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about `e.target` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `event.target.id` as `event.target` will return `element` on which `event` is `invoked` and `id` is a property of the `DOMElement`

[**`Event.target`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), A reference to the object that dispatched the event.

```js
var d1 = document.getElementById("d1");
var d2 = document.getElementById("d2");
var d3 = document.getElementById("d3");

function showme(event) {
  if (event.target.id == 'd3') {
    alert("hello")
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    alert("hello");
  }
};

d1.addEventListener("click", showme);
d2.addEventListener("click", showme);
d3.addEventListener("click", showme);
```

```css
#d1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#d2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#d3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2">
    <div id="d3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much...Just out of curiosity, the original way I had written the if statement ((d3.onclick == true)) was it checking for anything at all?

Comment: First of all, Use `console.log(expression)` for debugging.. Check `console.log(d3.onclick)` and see the value in `Developers tools`